# How to make mouse stop shaking after releasing mouse button in Python using pynput library?

Tags: python, pynput

The code is meant to shake the cursor whilst a key or mouse button is being held down, the key part works but when you try to use it with a mouse button it doesn't stop shaking after releasing.

I want the mouse to stop shaking after the Mousebutton is no longer being held down.
When I hold the Mousebutton down and then let go, the shaking continues. If anyone has what I'm doing wrong could you please let me know? I've been stuck on this for 35+ mins and have tried literally everything I know what do.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from pynput import keyboard, mouse
import win32api
import win32con
from pynput.mouse import Listener

# Global variables
is_aiming = False
current_key = None
move_cursor_id = None


def on_key_press(key):
    global is_aiming, current_key
    if isinstance(key, keyboard.KeyCode):
        current_key = key
        if key.char.lower() == key_entry.get().lower() and not is_aiming:
            is_aiming = True
            move_cursor()


def on_key_release(key):
    global is_aiming
    if isinstance(key, keyboard.KeyCode) and key == current_key:
        is_aiming = False


def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, _):
    global is_aiming, current_key
    if isinstance(button, mouse.Button) and button.name.lower() == key_entry.get().lower():
        current_key = button
        if not is_aiming:
            is_aiming = True
            move_cursor()


def on_mouse_release(x, y, button, _):
    global is_aiming, move_cursor_id
    if isinstance(button, mouse.Button) and button == current_key:
        is_aiming = False
        if move_cursor_id is not None:
            window.after_cancel(move_cursor_id)
            move_cursor_id = None
            if button == mouse.Button.left:
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            elif button == mouse.Button.right:
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)


def on_mouse_move(x, y):
    global is_aiming, move_cursor_id
    if is_aiming and move_cursor_id is None:
        move_cursor_id = window.after(10, move_cursor)


def move_cursor():
    global move_cursor_id
    if is_aiming:
        offset_x = random.randint(-1, 1)
        offset_y = random.randint(-1, 1)
        current_x, current_y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        new_x = current_x + offset_x
        new_y = current_y + offset_y
        win32api.SetCursorPos((new_x, new_y))
        move_cursor_id = window.after(10, move_cursor)
    else:
        if move_cursor_id is not None:
            window.after_cancel(move_cursor_id)
            move_cursor_id = None


# Create Tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Cursor Aiming")

# Create a label and entry field for the key
key_label = tk.Label(window, text="Key:")
key_label.pack()
key_entry = tk.Entry(window)
key_entry.pack()

# Start listening for key and mouse events
key_listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_key_press, on_release=on_key_release)
key_listener.start()

mouse_listener = Listener(
    on_click=on_mouse_press, on_release=on_mouse_release, on_move=on_mouse_move)
mouse_listener.start()

# Start monitoring the mouse for movement
mouse_controller = mouse.Controller()
mouse_controller.position = (0, 0)
mouse_controller.position = (1, 1)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I expect for the shaking to stop after the mouse button is no longer being held down.

Comment: the *"mouse is shaking"* ?  this sounds like a hardware problem, like a wobbly table...

Comment: also `mouse_controller.position = (1, 1)` will just set the cursor to the top right corner of the screen...  did you want to do this ?

Comment: Yes I did, also the program is intended to shake the mouse when the key is held down.

Comment: ...But the cursor does not shake when the mouse is pressed or the key is down. So resolving this problem would precede solving it stopping from shaking...  (when i run the code, i cannot get the cursor to shake).

Comment: The code is meant to be run on visual studio because it uses a gui, it works if you input it from there.

Comment: i used vs code,  it launched the `gui`, but i could not replicate the "wobble" with key presses or mouse clicks...

Comment: It should work? It works fine for me? In the input field enter a key and hold it down to see it working and to see the mouse issue enter left or right and hold it down to see the issue.